# If parentheses close the sentence, where should period be?

Tags: punctuation, parentheses, periods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In which cases is a comma/period placed inside or outside of parentheses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/in-which-cases-is-a-comma-period-placed-inside-or-outside-of-parentheses)

Consider the following sentence:

> Now, it is highly attributable that professionally I never had to
>   write any Swing code (or, for that matter, had a chance to look at Swing code others
>   have written)

In this sentence, where should the period be? After the closing `)` or before opening `(`?