# full-stop / period before or after closing bracket?

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In which cases is a comma/period placed inside or outside of parentheses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/in-which-cases-is-a-comma-period-placed-inside-or-outside-of-parentheses)

Is the convention (write something in brackets.) And start a new sentence.

or is it (More like this). And the other confusing factor below.

Is a sentence (like this?) Because the question mark belongs to what's in brackets.

So (is this)? More wrong because you're de-questioning the bracketed-sentence?

OK so some of those are decidedly bad english but you get the point. I hope?)?.?.